# Apache Ignite nodes cannot cluster - communication issue

Tags: ignite

We have recently started to build a test Ignite cluster and facing the TCP discovery issues. Several responses to similar issues discussed in this forum did not answer my query. In our test system, there are two Debian nodes in different subnets with no ports blocked and each node bootstraps Ignite as expected; all typical ports used were verified via Curl and we see no issues there.  In addition, these nodes use Cassandra cluster for persistent database and we have verified there are no issues loading the data into Ignite cache on each node.  The version of Ignite we are exploring is "apache-ignite-2.8.0" and TCP discovery is through TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder.

Both the ignite nodes display the following "Connection refused" error; the log contains no information (even after enabling DEBUG option for the logs) regarding the IP address of the connection.  We observed using "netstat -lntpa" that no connections are coming through from one node to the other.

```
[ERROR][main][TcpDiscoverySpi] Exception on direct send: Connection refused (Connection refused)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
   at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.openSocket(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1538)
   at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.openSocket(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1500)
   at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.sendMessageDirectly(ServerImpl.java:1307)
   at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.sendJoinReq`enter code here`uestMessage(ServerImpl.java:1142)
   at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:955)
   at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:422)
   at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2065)
   at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:297)
   at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:940)
   at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1736)
   at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1080)
   at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1992)
   at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1683)
   at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1109)
   at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1027)
   at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:913)
   at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:812)
   at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:682)
   at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:651)
   at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:346)
   at com.procurant.common.ignite.CommandLineStartup.startIgnite(CommandLineStartup.java:17)
   at com.procurant.common.ignite.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:82)
```

Ignite configuration file has the following parameters for one of the nodes: (the time out values did not play any significant role, the error is the same without them)

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
   <!-- Initial local port to listen to. -->
   <property name="localPort" value="45500" />
   <!-- Changing local port range. This is an optional action. -->
   <!-- Default jointTimeout=0 means wait for ever -->
   <property name="localPortRange" value="20" />
   <property name="networkTimeout" value="10000" />
   <property name="socketTimeout" value="30000" />
   <property name="joinTimeout" value="30000" />
   <property name="reconnectCount" value="5" />
   <property name="ackTimeout" value="10000" />
   <property name="ipFinder">
     <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
     <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
     <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">-->
       <property name="addresses">
         <list>
           <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
           <value>10.10.0.91:45500..45520</value>
         </list>
       </property>
     </bean>
   </property>
 </bean>
```

Any help and suggestion is appreciated to resolve our issues.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a chance that you have corresponding ports closed? It looks like an issue with the network.

Comment: No ports have been closed, in fact, opened all ports to check our connections.  Specific ports were checked using Curl (like 10800, 47100, 47500, etc.).  Debian Linux instance has no internal firewall to begin with, so no issues with that blocking any ports. We would like to know if there is a simple procedure to check the TcpDiscoverySpi we have chosen is working fine.

Comment: Could you please check whether you can establish a connection to the host via 45500?

Comment: What do you mean by Ignite 2.8? Are you using the nightly development build? The current release is 2.7.

Comment: Yes, each node can connect to other on port 45500. Our development team is using a specific 2.8 build (2019-02-15).

Comment: After following the guidelines in https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/tcpip-discovery, it became clear that both local IP address and one/more remote IPs should be in the configuration file.  This seemed to resolve our issues, however it is simply a static discovery.  We will be pursuing Zookeeper implementation to dynamically discover nodes to join the cluster.  Thanks!